# table grid lines and column colors in PySimpleGui

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I'm designing an app with PySimpleGui, and I want to create a table that looks something like this:

[image]

I was able to create a table with the appropriate column headings, but I can't find anything in the docs about how to display grid lines or set the background color for individual columns.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's no way for grid lines in `sg.Table`, also no way for column background color. Maybe you can use other elements to simulate a table, like https://github.com/jason990420/PySimpleGUI-Solution/issues/31

Comment: @JasonYang, thank you for the link.  It seems like an awful lot of trouble for what is basically a cosmetic issue, but I might be stuck with it if that's what the user wants.

Answer (score -1):

1. import PySimpleGUI as sg

   ```
    sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')

    Sheet=[] menu_opt=[
                ['&File',['&New','&Save','&Clear','E&xit']],
                ['&Edit',['&Undo','C&opy','&Paste']]
                ]

    menu=[sg.Menu(menu_opt)]

    Sheet.append(menu)

    AZ='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

    headers=[sg.T(L,size=(5,1),relief='raised',enable_events
    =True,k=str(L)) for L in AZ]

    for r in range(0,30):
        Sheet.append([sg.I(size=(5,1),background_color='White',k=str(L)+str(r))
    for L in AZ])

    layout=[
            headers,
            [sg.Column(Sheet,scrollable=True)],
            [sg.StatusBar('Sheet 1')]
            ]

    window=sg.Window('SpreadSheet',layout,element_padding=0,size=(600,370))

    while True:
        event,values=window.read()

        if event==sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='Exit':
            break
        if event:
            for r in range(0,30):
                window[event+str(r)].update(background_color='Yellow')

    window.close()
   ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please format your answer nicely and maybe add some text description, it will improve!